# Wildflyにデプロイをロールバックする機能はあるか？

Tags: jboss, wildfly

Wildflyにデプロイしてあるモジュールを入れ替えたあと、何か障害が発生したために、１つ前のモジュールに戻す（改めてデプロイする）というケースはよく（？）あると思うのですが、Wildflyの機能として、デプロイをロールバックするような機能はあるのでしょうか？
ニーズはありそうだから、機能としてあるんじゃないか、と思ったのですが。

Answer (score 0):

WildFly 8から`runtime-failure-causes-rollback`というプロパティが導入されているようですが、これは意図したものと異なりますか？

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
    <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000" 
        runtime-failure-causes-rollback="${jboss.deployment.scanner.rollback.on.failure:false}"/>
</subsystem>
```

> **runtime-failure-causes-rollback**
>
> Whether a runtime failure of a deployment causes a rollback of the deployment as well as all other (possibly unrelated) deployments as part of the scan operation.

https://wildscribe.github.io/WildFly/10.0/subsystem/deployment-scanner/scanner/index.html